# Left join query of user profiles

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following left join LINQ query that is returning the results that I expect, but it does not "feel" right. I need **ALL** records from the `UserProfile` table.

Then the `LastWinnerDate` is a single record from the winner table (possible multiple records) indicating the `DateTime` the last record was entered in that table for the user.

- `WinnerCount` is the number of records for the user in the `winner` table (possible multiple records).
- `Video1` is basically a `bool` indicating there is, or is not a record for the user in the `winner` table matching on a third table `Objective` (should be 1 or 0 rows).
- `Quiz1` is same as `Video1` matching another record from `Objective` Table (should be 1 or 0 rows).
- `Video` and `Quiz` is repeated 12 times because they're used for a report, which is to be displayed to a user listing all user records and indicate if they have met the objectives.

```
var objectiveIds = new List<int>();
objectiveIds.AddRange(GetObjectiveIds(objectiveName, false));

var q =
    from up in MetaData.UserProfile
    select new RankingDTO
    {
        UserId = up.UserID,
        FirstName = up.FirstName,
        LastName = up.LastName,
        LastWinnerDate = (
            from winner in MetaData.Winner
            where objectiveIds.Contains(winner.ObjectiveID)
            where winner.Active
            where winner.UserID == up.UserID
            orderby winner.CreatedOn descending
            select winner.CreatedOn).First(),
        WinnerCount = (
            from winner in MetaData.Winner
            where objectiveIds.Contains(winner.ObjectiveID)
            where winner.Active
            where winner.UserID == up.UserID
            orderby winner.CreatedOn descending
            select winner).Count(),
        Video1 = (
            from winner in MetaData.Winner
            join o in MetaData.Objective on winner.ObjectiveID equals o.ObjectiveID
            where o.ObjectiveNm == Constants.Promotions.SecVideo1
            where winner.Active
            where winner.UserID == up.UserID
            select winner).Count(),
        Quiz1 = (
            from winner2 in MetaData.Winner
            join o2 in MetaData.Objective on winner2.ObjectiveID equals o2.ObjectiveID
            where o2.ObjectiveNm == Constants.Promotions.SecQuiz1
            where winner2.Active
            where winner2.UserID == up.UserID
            select winner2).Count(),
    };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't feel right, because you have a lot of repetitive code.

Notice how each property selector's where statement contains

```
        where objectiveIds.Contains(winner.ObjectiveID)
        where winner.Active
        where winner.UserID == up.UserID
```

That means you can refactor this where condition to a join in the containing query.

Also, you specify an `order by` clause, when you are only using the values to get the `Count()`.  This does nothing but take up space and time.

I think **this query** might be more along the line of what you are trying to achieve:

```
        var rankingDtos = 
                    from user in MetaData.UserProfile
                    let userWinners = from winner in MetaData.Winner
                                      let objectives = from objective in MetaData.Objective
                                                       where winner.ObjectiveID == objective.ObjectiveID
                                                       select objective
                                      where winner.UserID == user.UserID && winner.Active
                                      orderby winner.CreatedOn descending
                                      select new
                                                 {
                                                     Winner = winner,
                                                     Objectives = objectives
                                                 }
                    select new RankingDTO
                               {
                                   UserId = user.UserID,
                                   FirstName = user.FirstName,
                                   LastName = user.LastName,
                                   LastWinnerDate = userWinners.First().Winner.CreatedOn,
                                   WinnerCount = userWinners.Count(x => objectiveIds.Contains(x.Winner.ObjectiveID)),
                                   Video1 = userWinners.Count(x => x.Objectives.Any(o => o.ObjectiveNm == Constants.Promotions.SecVideo1)),
                                   Quiz1 = userWinners.Count(x => x.Objectives.Any(o => o.ObjectiveNm == Constants.Promotions.SecQuiz1))
                               };
```

Answer (score 1):

What LINQ is this? Entities? ESQL, linq to sql? linq to objects?

If Linq to SQL then:

Try this and see what the resulting SQL is then decide based on the sql, or profile the sql itself on your db?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// From BReusable
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dc"></param>
    /// <remarks>http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/08/17/DataContextLogLoggingLINQToSQLOutputConsoleDebuggerOuputWindow.aspx</remarks>
    public static void SendQueriesToConsole(this DataContext dc)
    {
        dc.Log = Console.Out;
    }
```